# How to use my customers' email sending their email as the "Sender"

Tags: php, email, email-client

I used to use "Php mailer" to authenticate using a user's email and password to send from their address in my app, but it is such an inconvenience.

So I want to do something like "Mailchimp" does. Mailchimp allows a user to set their email and then Mailchimp just uses user's email as the "Sender".

Please anyone help me with this email issue.

Comment: It is not clear whether you currently use `Mailchimp` or you are just giving example of a functionality they have and you would like to mimic.

Comment: If you try to kinda fake their email address, depending on setup, your mails will be marked as spam or bounced completely. You should really go for a different way of sending emails.

Comment: Don't do this except if your server is explicitly authorized to send email by the domain SPF records of the address you want to use as sender. Or you'll end in spam and possibly get your server blacklisted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. MailChimp requires you to verify yourself as the owner of the e-mail address and domain through DNS settings. [See more details](http://mailchimp.com/about/authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is first verify the user's email address is correct. Here is a good walk-through that shows how to do that:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-implement-email-verification-for-new-members--net-3824

You'll also want a disclaimer as proof that they have given you permission to send emails on their behalf.

```
 Disclaimer: by enrolling for this service you are granting this 
 app permission to send emails on your behalf.
```

Next you'll want to create a functional email account that belongs to your app only. For example:

```
 clientmailer@myapp.com
```

Then, last but not least- continue to use PHPMailer, but use it differently. Authenticate and send emails from your app's functional account, but set the AddReplyTo address as your customer's address and name. For example:

```
 select email, firstname from client;
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';
 $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
 $mail->Host       = yourhost@myapp.com;
 $mail->Port       = EMAIL_PORT;
 $mail->Username   = clientmailer@myapp.com;
 $mail->Password   = yourpass;
 $mail->SetFrom('clientmailer@myapp.com', 'Functional Mailer');
 $mail->AddReplyTo('(email from select)', '(firstname from select)');
```